# IBM Mobilefirst CLI 7.1.0 error with mfp start and mfp push

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud, command-line-interface

When I type "mfp start" in the terminal, this is what I get:

> Initializing MobileFirst Console. objc[64598]: Class JavaLaunchHelper
>   is implemented in both
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
>   (0x1075964c0) and
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib
>   (0x1076904e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
>   Starting server worklight. Server worklight start failed. Check server
>   logs for details.
>   **Error: The server failed to start. The port may be in use by another instance of a running server, or the server may not exist.**

when I type "mfp push" into the terminal, this is what I get:

> Preparing for push... Verifying Server Configuration...
>
> Runtime 'DoorbellIOSNative' will be used to push the project into.
>   **Error: JAVA_HOME environment variable must be set and pointing to a Java Development Kit (JDK). See 'mobilefirst help build'. Error: error
>   code: 304 Error: There was an error building the application. Error:
>   undefined Error: Push has failed**

How do I fix these issues and errors? I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the CLI and I also have updated my java version to the latest version. I have also typed "mfp stop" in the terminal and typed in "mfp start" again but still got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Verify you do not have an already running server or something else is listening to the same port.  Another thing you might want to check is the /etc/hosts file contains the right IP address for the localhost.

Double check to make sure your JAVA_HOME is set to the JDK, not JRE. Based on your first error, it should be:
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: how do I verify that I do not already have a running server or something else listening to the same port? And how do I get the correct UP address for the local host?

Comment: IP* address for the local host